# Query to check any column with null value

Tags: oracle11g

How to show `ptr_forecast_dt` as NULL if `ptr_actual_dt` has some value in query otherwise show `ptr_forecast_dt`

Please suggest how can I write query in Oracle

```
SELECT MAX (a.ptr_planned_dt)  AS ptr_planned_dt,
       MAX (a.ptr_forecast_dt) AS ptr_forecast_dt,
       MAX (a.ptr_actual_dt)   AS ptr_actual_dt
  FROM ptr_details a
```

Comment: You say you have 2 questions, but they seem to be the same to me.

Comment: Why do you use the tag "mysql", if it's an Oracle question?

Comment: Means if ptr_forecast_dt is null then should print ptr_actual_dt Else print ptr_forecast_dt

Comment: By using `decode()` function or searched `case` expression.

Comment: Could you please tell how can I use case in above query

Answer (score 1):

You can you NVL2 - NVL2 (value,  return_value_if_not_null,  return_value_if_null)

or a combination of nvl and decode or case

e.g.

```
select MAX (a.ptr_planned_dt)  AS ptr_planned_dt,
       nvl2(max(a.ptr_actual_dt),max(a.ptr_forecast),null) as ptr_forecast_dt,
       MAX (a.ptr_actual_dt)   AS ptr_actual_dt
from ptr_details a
```

Comment: How to use case for the above query

Comment: I tend to recommend using `COALESCE` over `NVL` or `NVL2`. It offers several advantages: it's the ANSI standard; it accepts n arguments, so it has more functionality than either of the earlier functions; and it supports short-circuit evaluation, so any calculations after the first non-null value are skipped.

Comment: I'd agree with that - I only suggested nvl2 as I originally misread the question, but it offers a nice combination of nvl and decode. In the case of ANSI sql COALESCE is the one to use